# CakePHP 2.x afterSave() return value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the **afterSave()** callback to clear out some cached queries for my model.  I checked the documentation but it does not say if TRUE/FALSE should be returned.  For **beforeSave()** you need to return TRUE/FALSE.  The callback header look like this:

**afterSave(boolean $created, array $options = array())**

My initial thought was that I should just return **$created** but it just isnt clear.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The value of $created will be true if a new record was created
>   (rather than an update)."

So returing $created isnt the right choice its just there to help you coding :).

You dont have to return anything because the data is already saved and you just modify it in this function.

Remember that callback methods are triggered after behavior functions!

GL